# 値を学習して決めて、計算結果を評価とするPythonの強化学習はありますか？

Tags: python, keras

Pythonで強化（深層）学習をしたいのですが、どのようなライブラリを使えばいいのかわかりません。したいことは以下のとおりです。

１．値を決定
２．その値を元に演算
３．演算の結果が大きい方がスコアが高い
４．スコアと値の関係性を学習
１’．学習内容を元に値を決定
２．その値を元に演算
︙
最後．一番スコアが高いときの値を出力

なにか情報があれば些細なことでも教えていただきたいです。

ー追加ー
kerasでやってみようと思います。しかし調べ方が悪いのか、1ステップの中に何度も値を決定するような例かMinstのような先に模範解答がわかっててそれと合っているかでスコアを出す例しか見つかりません。なにか上のような流れのプログラムの例はありませんでしょうか。

Comment: 演算が固定（いわゆる関数y=f(x)）であるならば、AIは必要なくて数学で求められると思います。

Comment: 要するに単に強化学習のためのライブラリを見つけたいという趣旨なのかなと解釈しましたが、あっていますでしょうか？　質問文に書かれてある手順は一般的な強化学習の手順をそのまま書いたように見えました。"python reinforcement learning library" などと検索すると分かるように色々あるので、もう少し具体的にどういう問題について取り組もうとなさっているのか分かるように質問を [edit] いただけないでしょうか。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。下に追加という形で書かせていただきました。

Answer (score 0):

Keras で強化学習がしたいということであれば、Keras 自体のドキュメントにコード例が載っているので参考になりそうです: https://keras.io/examples/rl/

ただし、強化学習というのはあくまで学習方法の分類の名前であり、「強化学習」という名前の具体的な実装がある訳ではありません。どのような目的を達成したいのかによって何を実装すべきかが変わるので、そのあたりも調べてみてください。